# How to move the bootloader (Windows 8)

Tags: boot, windows-8

I have two disks in my computer ( a 80GB SSD ) and a normal 250GB (OLD DRIVE). I installed windows on the SSD.

I now want to remove my 250GB drive as its old and slow, but when i remove it windows dont boot up. Error is printed to insert a boot disk (bios error, cant remember exactly what it was, but i think peolpe know what im talking about, else i will find out and update).

I assume its because the bootloader is on this 250GB drive, and wonder how to move it such i can throw out the old disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these simple steps:

1. Boot from your Windows 8 install DVD.
2. At the initial screen, pick `Repair your computer`.
3. Then `Troubleshoot` -> `Advanced Options` and finally `Command Prompt`.
4. At this command prompt, enter: `bootrec /RebuildBCD` (to rebuild boot configuration)
5. and then `bootrec /FixBoot`  (to write a new boot sector)

Comment: I am getting an Element not found error doing this

Comment: using diskpart to make the partition with windows on active first made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your unneeded 250 gigabyte drive.  Then, start up a Linux LiveCD or USB containing GParted (or get it [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php)).  GParted is a graphical partition manager that allows you to easily modify partitions.  Use it to mark the "boot" flag as on on your Windows partition in your SSD.

Then, run Startup Repair from your Windows install disc.  It should automatically restore your Windows's boot ability, but if it doesn't, navigate to command prompt and run `bootrec /RebuildBCD`.  This will create a new Master Boot Record, which tells your computer where to look for the operating system.  Restart your computer without the CD in the tray and enjoy!