# How to rebuild bootloader after migration to SSD (win8.1 x64)?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-8.1, ssd

I've initially installed win 8.1 x64 in my hard disk.
Αfterwards that I bought a M2 SSD, I installed  win 8.1 x64 to it, too.
Then I deleted the windows-related folders from the hard disk.
**The problem is that bootmgr is kept in the hard disk.**
So, in order the system to boot, it has to read firstly from the hard disk (DD:) where the bootmgr resides.
If -instead of the hard disk- I try to boot the system choosing the SSD in BIOS (UEFI)
I get an error message and a prompt to press either:

- Enter(retry), or
- Esc (for UEFI options) or
- F8 (for boot options).

**So, I want to move it to the SSD for faster boot times

and in order the hard disk not to be required for booting anymore.**

---

Based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/467008/298991) I've already tried these two solutions:

---

**1st:**

1. Boot from your Windows 8 install DVD.
2. At the initial screen, pick `Repair your computer`.
3. Then `Troubleshoot` -> `Advanced Options` and finally `Command Prompt`.
4. At this command prompt, enter: `bootrec /RebuildBCD` (to rebuild boot configuration)
5. and then `bootrec /FixBoot` (to write a new boot sector)

but the problem is that I get `"Element not found"`.
If I use diskpart, and then select disk 2 and select partition 2
it finds my installation, but when I try to add it to boot list it says `element not found`.

---

**2st:**

I tried EasyBCD 2.2 (based on [this guide](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/209885-bootmgr-move-c-easybcd.html) ) in order to copy bootmgr to C:
i.e [image]
but what I get is

`An attempt was made to change the boot partition to a logical drive which is not allowed. The boot partition must be a primary partition. Please either select a different drive or convert the selected partition to primary first, then try again.`

Also I've found that changing the SSD from GUID (as it currently is) to MBR might fix the problem,
but from what I've read (http://www.howtogeek.com/193669/whats-the-difference-between-gpt-and-mbr-when-partitioning-a-drive/)
GUID is much better than the (old) MBR in every aspect,
so I don't think that it's worth messing with it.

Comment: Post a screenshot of disk management with the two disks installed.

Comment: Here it is: https://i.imgur.com/0eyT8It.jpg

Comment: Ssd disk is missing the system partition, needed by windows. There reside all the necessary files to correctly boot the system. You should delete partition and reinstall windows with the other disk detached so windows setup will create the system partition during os setup. If you have spare time, you can try to manually resize the partition, manually create a new empty partition of 100MiB at start of disk and then perform the windows repair to see if windows setup can rebuils the system partition for you.